# regex skip embedded patterns

Tags: php, regex

I am filtering some text with php.  I look for patterns like:

```
Mary [qtip:had|past tense of have] little lamb.
```

I extract the anchor text "had" from the tool tip "past tense of have"]

part of the processing is to use the regular expression `/\[qtip:([^\|\\]]+)\|?([^\\]]*)?\]/`

this is working fine

I am trying to extend the functionality.

```
Mary [qtip:had|past [otherFunction:tense|verb form signalling time] of have] little lamb.
```

my simple minded pattern finds `"had"` & `"past [otherFunction:tense|verb form indicating time"`

I want a pattern which will skip embedded `[]` pairs.  These are not allowed in anchor or tool tip.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you escape the `|` and double escape the `]`? And to solve your problem, simply disallow opening `[` inside your pattern. That requires the pattern to reach the closing `]` without encountering any nested square brackets.

```
preg_match_all('/\[qtip:([^|[\]]+)\|?([^[\]]*)\]/', $input, $matches);
```

I also removed the last `?` since it is redundant if you use use `*` on the pattern that should become optional.